# How to customize user profile in MembershipReboot

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, membershipreboot

I just integrated the MembershipReboot to my Thinktecture Identity server V2. Now ,I would like to extend user profile like firstname, lastname, facebook, twitter, etc..

Is there any way that I can do it like in ASP.NET membership provider just need to modify config file only with MembershipReboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the MR sample implements the IClaimsRepository interface -- this is the interface you need to implement to expose claims for the tokens issued from IdentityServer.

Comment: do you mean that I have to implement this interface on my codes? so I can't just revise the profile configuration to achieve my require,right?
I know there is a "CustomizationsSample" at MembershipReboot github and I am looking into it.

Comment: Well, the built-in profile support was using ASP.NET Profile provider. MR doesn't use the Profile provider and has its own store for identity data.